# Getting exception error for java login servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am trying to create a login servlet but keep receiving this error? I am new to programming so don't quite understand what this means. I have looked up this error but cant see what I am doing wrong? Any help appreciated. This is the error

```
Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it 
from fulfilling the request.
```

> Exception 
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the 
>       response has been committed
>        org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:488)
>       Loginn.processRequest(Loginn.java:52)
>       Loginn.doPost(Loginn.java:71)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

This is my code

```
public class Loginn extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try(PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 
    {

       String name = request.getParameter("name");
       String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
       MyDb1 db = new MyDb1();
       Connection con = db.getCon();
       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select uid,name,pass from register where email = '"+name+"' and  pass = '"+pass+"'");

      while ((rs.next())) {

          String uid = rs.getString("uid");

          HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
          session.setAttribute("name",uid);
          response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Final_Year_Project_5_/userprofile.jsp");  
      } 


 }catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Loginn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
 }
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
} 

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
 }
}
```

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-sendredirect-create-session

Comment: Can you post your `JSP` code?  That you are using? And what method are you using? `POST` or `GET`

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352632/how-to-fix-cannot-call-sendredirect-after-the-response-has-been-committed

Comment: Are you sure you're getting only one DB record from your query? Change `while ((rs.next())) {` to `if ((rs.next())) {` to prevent multiple redirects.

Comment: Side note: never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: I am using a post method

Comment: @Moladhh So why do you code in `processRequest`. Put your code under `doPost` method and replace `while` with `if` as @Jozef said

Answer (score 0):

use request distpatcher instead of sendRedirect

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/userprofile.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```